# How to Disable Html codes in chat script

Tags: php, html, mysql

I Have Created A simple Chat
script m using mysql fetch array to
show the text written by users but a
lot of users using html codes in text
box and Changing my site configs [like Text color adding Images]
please help me how to show the entered Html code as plaintext ?

Comment: Try reading the manual? http://php.net/htmlspecialchars http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before outputting the text use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
$message = htmlspecialchars($message);
echo $message;
```

This wil convert the special characters so they are just printed out to the screen instead of processed as HTML.

Strip_tags() will remove them alltogether, not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) for that.

**An example of what it does:**

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this a couple ways:

- `html_entities($message);` Would change tag symbols into character codes, so that they would display as the character but have no function (probably the best way)
- `strip_tags($message);` to completely delete any tag symbols

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use [`strip_tags();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove HTML formatting for the chat messages